# Explanation for this Webpack config

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Im having a hard time trying to understand what the variable below does in my webpack config.

```
var devPort = optimist.argv.port || 8080;
```

webpack-dev-server normally runs on localhost:8080. 
There is a HotModuleReplacementPlugin and this variable is later called for development build as follows:

```
var publicPath = '';
if (mode.IS_HOT) {
   publicPath = 'http://localhost:' + devPort + '/';
}
```

What would the publicPath be set to according to this variable ie. "optimist.argv.port || 8080" ?

Comment: You mean that you don't know what the syntax `optimist.argv.port || 8080` does ?

Comment: Correct Arnaud...I am aware that optimist is a Node lib..but not quite sure what this syntax is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `devPort` will get the value of `optimist.argv.port` if it's not `false`.

Otherway, it will be equal to 8080.

Generically, the variable is assigned the nearest non-falsy value.

```
var john = false || null || undefined || '' || 'Doe' || 'Jane';
```

john has the value `Doe`

By the way, it's not a Webpack specific syntax. It's a common JavaScript one.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud. Appreciate the help!